# How to bind ngmodel inside each item in for loop angular 8?

Tags: checkbox, angular8, ngmodel

I want deselect the radio button, but after searching alot..I didn't find answer. So I choose the way of making checkbox work as a radio button(only single selection).And it worked fine but when I'm not able to bind ngmodel to checkbox.
I want the checkbox like

- Item1
  Id
  Name
- Item2
  Id
  Name
- Item3
  Id
  Name

I need to select one checkbox item from the list of item (one from Id and Name).

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code with use of [(ngModel)].

HTML

```
<div *ngFor = "let item of data ; let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" [(ngModel)]="item.IsSelected" (change)="toggleSelection(i)" /> {{item.name}}
</div>
```

Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  data : any = [
    {'id': 1 , 'name': 'item-1'},
    {'id': 2 , 'name': 'item-2'},
    {'id': 3 , 'name': 'item-3'},
    {'id': 4 , 'name': 'item-4'}
  ];

 toggleSelection(i){
   this.data.forEach((item, index) => {
     if(index != i){
       this.data[index].IsSelected = false
     }
   })
  }

  getSelectedItem(){
    const selectedItem = this.data.filter( (item) => item.IsSelected );
    console.log("selected option is ", selectedItem);
  }

}
```